# passing struct in a struct to pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

wanting to save memory I had the following Idea:

```
    struct data{

        double **A;
        double **B;
        double **C;
     };

    struct param{
        struct data *v; // A,B,C
        int n, i;
    };

void* runner( void* param) {return;}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int threads=10;

    int **A,**B,**C;

    struct data v;
    v.A=A;
    v.B=B;
    v.C=C;
    struct param *Parameter;
    Parameter=malloc(threads*sizeof(struct param*));

    for(int i=0;i<threads;i++)
    {
        Parameter[i].v=&v;
        Parameter[i].i=0;
        Parameter[i].n=threads;
    }


    pthread_t* threadNumber;

    threadNumber = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*threads);

    for (int i =0 ;i<threads;++i)
        pthread_create(&threadNumber[i],NULL,matrix_vector,(void*) Parameter[i]);


    for(int i=0;i<threads;++i)
        pthread_join(threadNumber[i],NULL);
return 0;
}
```

However the compiler says: 100:9: error: cannot convert to a pointer type
(in pthread_create, argument 4)
which is expectable, but I have no idea how to fix it in that style?
Thanks for tips!

Comment: You want the address of `Parameter[i]`, so `(void *) &Parameter[i]`

Comment: omg, so cheap. Thank you very much!

Comment: OT: No need to cast to/from `void`-pointers in C.

Comment: Also this `Parameter=malloc(threads*sizeof(struct param*));` is not what you want, but `Parameter=malloc(threads*sizeof(struct param));` or even more safe: `Parameter=malloc(threads*sizeof *Parameter);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Parameter[i]` is of type `struct param` which is not coercible to `void *` in C, to the best of my knowledge, so you probably want to pass its address actually, which is either

```
Parameter + i
```

or

```
&Parameter[i]
```